# Can't preload a function in C program

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I wrote some code in nasm and I'm trying to implement it in a C program as a replacement of strlen through a shared library, but it doesn't work.

nasm code:

```
        section .text  
        global  strlen:function

strlen:
    mov     rax, 42
    ret
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t strlen(const char *s);

int main()
{
  printf("%zu\n", strlen("foobar"));
  return (0);
}
```

I compile the C program just using gcc without any arguments, and I create the shared library with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 strlen.asm
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libasm.so strlen.o
```

Finally, I include the shared library:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libasm.so
```

But it displays '6' where I expect it to display '42'.
I don't think the problem comes from my library, because I get segmentation fault when I execute the ls command with LD_PRELOAD.

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to `nasm` at all.  A `C` equivalent of your `strlen()` function does not work either.

```
$ cat strlen.c 
#include <stddef.h>

size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    return 43;
}

$ cat s.c
#include <stdio.h>

size_t strlen(const char *s);

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", strlen("foobar"));

    return 0;
}

$ make s
cc     s.c   -o s

$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o strlen.so strlen.c

$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/strlen.so ./s
6
```

What is happening here is that `gcc` is using its own built-in version of `strlen()` that cannot be overridden.  If the `C` program that calls `strlen()` is recompiled to not use this built-in version of `strlen()`, then your shared library can override it.

```
$ rm s
$ make s CFLAGS=-fno-builtin-strlen
cc -fno-builtin-strlen    s.c   -o s

$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/strlen.so ./s
43

$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libasm.so ./s
42
```

Comment: I thought it would be related to nasm as I coded that in nasm, I removed the tag. Very interesting anyway, does gcc use built-ins of every libc functions ?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise libc would be unnecessary.  The gcc manual has more information on [built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)